# jQuery Mobile Swipe Error - Scrolling is in Progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, swipe

**The Expected Behavior**

I am trying to incorporate basic swipe functionality for a slideshow of content.  I swipe in either direction an it moves nicely to the next/previous slide.  The slides do not move when at either end and swiping can continue from there.

**The Problem**

When swiping, I am receiving the following error in my log after the slides move correctly:

"Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted."

I also find that when I reach the end of my slides and try to slide into the stopped direction again, the error triggers.  But when I try to then swipe back into the correct position, the swipe functionality no longer works.  It's as if the window is expecting the slides to animate but nothing is, which then prevents any additional functionality from triggering.

I have found no information on this error and have tried numerous debugging attempts and solution ideas but have had no luck yet.  Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
function swipeleftHandler(event) {
   changeInnerScene('left',true); 
}
function swiperightHandler(event) {
   changeInnerScene('right',true);
}

$(".frame-three").on({"swipeleft": swipeleftHandler, "swiperight": swiperightHandler});
```

Comment: Are you using any third party plugin?

Comment: I m not running any additional plugins.  I am loading jQuery and a custom jQuery Mobile build containing only the base functionality that I need.  The error/warning seems to be coming from jQuery though, not the mobile version.

Comment: Were you successful with the full version of JQuery Mobile? Because the code looks accurate.

Comment: I was not.  I also tried various versions of jQuery as well, since that is what is throwing the error, with no luck either.

Comment: Since the element that I am swiping and sliding are both nested, I have been reading about propagation but that hasn't seemed to get me anywhere either.

Comment: Did I miss it, or did you not describe the browser/device where this is happening? If you're using Chrome it sounds like this may be the cause: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/05/A-More-Compatible-Smoother-Touch

Comment: Try loading full version of JQM. Custom build might malfunction since it's not meant for production usage.

Comment: I guess it's not a coincidence you got this error 1 day after Google Chrome's latest release? Because I have the same problem for a different cause. Did this work before you reported this error?

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar use case, presenting the same bug. I have been reading about Chrome's throtled assynchronous touchmove events, and I thought that canceling the event at touchstart woudl fix it, but it didn't.

I am guessing that your element has its position set as absolute or fixed, am I right?

Changed it to relative and see if it works. In my case, it did.